# Passing a path in JSON from Javascript to C++ and back

Tags: javascript, c++, string, path

I have written a C++ module for my Node/Typescript/Javascript frontend and use JSON to pass data back and forth, e.g.

```
let response = myModule.addCommand("{\"cmd\":\"LoadFile\", \"path\":\"D:\\\\folder\\\\file.abc\"}");
```

However, I have trouble passing variables, as they are loosing the backslashes each time and so I am currently storing the path variable and use `regex` to add back the "lost" backslashes each time.

On the C++ side:

```cpp
std::filysystem::path cppPath = doc["path"].GetString(); // using rapidjson::Document doc
// do stuff
std::string response ="{\"path\":\"" +
      std::regex_replace(cppPath.string(), std::regex(R"(\\)"), R"(\\\\)") + 
      "\"}";
```

And on the JS/TS side:

```js
// from cpp:
let response = myModule.addCommand(`{\"cmd\":\"LoadFile\", \"path\":\"D:\\\\folder\\\\file.abc\"}`);
let regex = /\\/g;
let usedPath = response.path.replace(regex, "\\\\");
let response = myModule.addCommand(`{\"cmd\":\"SaveFile\", \"path\":\"${usedPath}\"}`);
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this to pass the variable directly so that it can be used on the other "side"?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First of all, on the JS side, you can use single quotes for the outer part of the string (i.e., `'your string'`). That will allow you to get rid of any backslash that you are currently using before a double quote, and it might help you see where the actual problem is.

Comment: You can get rid of a few headaches by using a proper JSON library on both sides. `JSON.stringify` is right there! Next, consider using forward slashes for paths instead of backslashes. They work equally well and do not need to be escaped.